# Fantasy book where in the end, a crippled exiled boy becomes king

Tags: story-identification

Last year I read a book which included all of these things:

- At the beginning of the book, a boy walking through an alley finds an old man running towards him, being chased by guards. The old guy dies after giving the boy a chest with a ancient scroll.
- Soon after, the boy returns home and finds his mother murdered by guards.
- The scroll belongs to a group of men sworn to protect it, only one old guy is left alive.
- Later on, the princess/queen is exiled by her evil brother.
- The princess/queen (Feya, or it started with a F) teams up with the boy to help save the kingdom.
- Crippled babies were killed so the kingdom could be perfect.
- At the end of the book, the queen dies and a young boy who was taken away so he didn't die at birth. He has a crippled leg and becomes the new king because he was born on the *x*th second of the *x*th minute of *x*th hour of the *x*th month, etc.

I've been looking forever for this trilogy.

Comment: Bad leg - becomes king; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Fire

Comment: Bad leg - Becomes king; http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11680080-quest-for-the-scorpion-s-jewel

Comment: Bad leg - Becomes king; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Winter_King

Comment: Bad leg - Becomes king; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Claudius_%28TV_series%29

Comment: When I read the title to this question, a vision of Bran Stark sat upon the Iron Throne popped in my head for some reason.

Comment: Can't help thinking that George Lucas could do something with this.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought that it might be the fairy tale "The Little Lame Prince and his Traveling Cloak" (1875) by Maria Dinah Mulock Craik, but the question gives a lot of details which are not in that story.  Thus It must be a different story unless WILLIAM CUTLER is combining details from several different stories in the same book.